# Sending Google Analytics event from cron

Tags: php, cron, google-analytics

I have a php script that sends events to Google, it is a common code block supplied by google, but it does have some php echo statements I have added to it.

It works fine when I run the page in a browser, but it does not work when I run it from a cron:

```
/usr/bin/lynx -dump (path to script)
```

The script runs from the cron (I have logging to a file), but in the case of running it from a cron, the event does not appear in analytics.

Something to do with the echo?

Comment: I think you need to show a bit of code. The only serverside GA scripts I know supplied by Google rely on $_SERVER and $_COOKIE-Variables which are not set on the command line. You could test if your script works if you place it on a web server and call it via wget in your cron.

Comment: Ah that would explain why it does not work from the command line. I am not sure I understand why it might work with wget, but not lynx, can you answer that? In the first post (path to script) is the url to the script on the server.

Comment: The idea was to place the script on a web server (so it has an url) and then call that url via wget (so the script runs effectively in the browser). Another idea is to manually construct a gif request and send it via CURL from your shell script - if you fill in all parameters in the gif request manually no server variables are needed.